# How to write custom functions for in memory HSQL

Tags: java, unit-testing, db2, hsqldb

I want to write a simple function in HSQL so that it is backwards compatible with DB2 functions. In theory I should be able to write a custom function in java and hook it into HSQL. Is there any direction/documentation on just that?

Answer (score 5):

User defined functions are documented in the HSQLDB Guide. See this section for functions written in Java.

http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/sqlroutines-chapt.html#src_jrt_routines

You can also write your functions in SQL, which is documented in the same chapter of the Guide.

Comment: Hi!! Do you mid helping me with this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/78247047/811293 Thanks in advance.